# I can't download my uploaded file in Laravel. It show file does not exist

Tags: database, laravel, file-upload, file-not-found, not-exists

In Laravel,
I uploaded file successfully in storage and also link storage with public. My uploaded directory like this,

[This is my download directory map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm6Tq.png)

This is my Download button code,

```
 <form action="{{route('download', $file->id)}} " method="get">
    @csrf
  <button type="submit" class="btn border-none btn-sm btn-primary">Download</button> 
   </form>
```

This is my Route setup for this ,

```
//Download uploaded file 
Route::get('/download/{file}', [UploadUserFileController::class, 'downloadfile'])->name('download')->middleware('auth');
```

This is my Controller code for this,

```
// Download requested file 

public function downloadfile($id){

    $filelink = File::find($id);


    // return Storage::disk('public')->download('./storage/files/'.$filelink->files);
    // return Storage::download('./files/'.$filelink->files);
    return response()->download('/storage/files/'.$filelink->files, $filelink->files);
}
```

But after I click Download button it show me this error,

**The file "/storage/files/Demand.pdf" does not exist**

I am new in Laravel, I am not understanding the problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I get my problem, My form was wrong , I was pass files wrong way.

Now, My problem was solved by using this,

```
<form action="{{route('download', $file->files)}} " method="get">
    @csrf
  <button type="submit" class="btn border-none btn-sm btn-primary">Download</button> 
   </form>
```